# Android device in portrait mode, need preview and photos in landscape

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm working on a custom camera app for Android.  The camera is windowed (NOT fullscreen).  So far, it's working pretty well in that I can see a camera preview, take photos & video, switch cameras (front & back).  However, what I need is when the device is in portrait mode, I need my SurfaceView to be landscape along with the photos taken.  Right now, on my test device, I have a SurfaceView set to an aspect of 5:3, with a supported preview size of 800x480 (also 5:3).  BUT, the camera preview looks stretched horizontally AND the photos taken end up 480x800 (3:5 aspect).

Is there any way to force the camera to take the photos as 800x480 while the device is in portrait mode, such that the camera preview is also a scaled version of 800x480?

Environment:
Android Studio 1.3.1 on OSX 10.10
Targeting API 15-23

Using Camera API, NOT Camera2.

Comment: every camera is in landscape mode we can change tha camera preview

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar can you explain.  I'm not following.

Comment: @MCLLC Have you found the solution yet?I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @Sunshinetpu No, not yet.  I've seen that the TextSecure built in camera looks landscape, but I do believe they are cropping the portrait preview to look landscape.  So, unless someone else has an idea, I may end up doing that.